# Interactive storyboard with Balsamiq Mockups or Mockups-like software?

Tags: user-interface, prototype, storyboard, mockups

I did my UI design using Balsamiq Mockups. Now they're just images. I was wondering if it's possible to construct an interactive storyboard. Basically I want the user to click a button and show the next UI screen associated to that button.

Basically I need to show this to the client and it's an early version so spending time to code the prototype is not really an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible with Balsamiq Mockups if you have the Desktop or Confluence version: you can make buttons and links clickable, and get them to show another mockup.

See this image [from documentation](http://balsamiq.com/support/documentation#links):

[image: Mockup link]

Comment: Where is the option to do that? I'm on the button but the edit panel doesn't show anything like that. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @dierre: do you have the properties panel open? Don't know why you don't have the link. Note that it's for version 1.6 and higher.